# How do I open a file within notepad++ with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I'm trying to get my c++ program to open an sql file in notepad++. I can get it to open with notepad like this:

```
system("notepad.exe script_foo.sql");
```

But that's undesirable as it's not formatted. When I try to substitute notepad.exe for notepad++.exe like this:

```
system("'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' script_foo.sql");
```

I get a invalid syntax error.

Any issues where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WinNT shell uses double-quotes to include spaces in a file name.  Single quotes are not recognized.  So you need

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" script_foo.sql
```

as your command.

To embed this in C++ source code, you'll need to escape backslashes (as Andre already mentioned) and also the double-quotes.

```
system("\"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" script_foo.sql");
```

Comment: That's the stuff! Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the backslash character `\` is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in strings.  You need to double the backslashes to achieve what you really want:

```
system("'C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe' script_foo.sql");
```

Comment: No dice: "The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Just a note: the script_foo.sql file is in the same dir as the exe file.

Comment: Single quotes ought to be escaped as well.  But the shell really wants you to use double quotes around a path with spaces.

Comment: @Ben: Hah, totally missed that one!